# Why does setting an item from one sub-array into another "super-array" change the value in the subarray (Mergesort)

Tags: java, list, debugging, arraylist, mergesort

My immediate thought was because the arrays pointed to the same location. Not true. I've tried making variables to bypass using the direct reference to the arraylist (`Rightset`) but all of them result in both the value inside the leftset and the ordered (Superarray) set being changed, even if the number entering the "superarray" (OrderingMatches) is from the rightset anyway! Was also having issues with simplying adding and removing despite it being less efficient.

Problem is at `OrderingMatches.set(OrderedCount, Rightset.get(Rightind));`

Shouldn't this replace the current value in `OrderingMatches`, with the `rightset.get` value.
Problem also occurs further down

Heres the entire mergesort code (Will need your own items because mine is massive)

```
public static void MergeSort(List<String> UnOrderedMatches, int Start, int ComparisonCount) {
    //int NumberOfContentsViable = Math.round(UnOrderedMatches.size() / 2);
    // NumberOfContentsViable > 1

    //UnOrderedMatches.isEmpty() != true

    int MidPoint;
    int Finish = UnOrderedMatches.size(); //sometimes erroneously passed in finish values so eliminate any opportunity for that to happen

    if (Finish > 1 && UnOrderedMatches.isEmpty() != true) {
        //testing values
        MidPoint = ((Start + Finish) / 2);

        List<String> LeftSet = UnOrderedMatches.subList(Start, MidPoint); //left 
        List<String> RightSet = UnOrderedMatches.subList(MidPoint, Finish); //right //+1

        //UnOrderedMatches.isEmpty() != true
        System.out.println("Created Sublists");
        MergeSort(LeftSet, Start, ComparisonCount);  //left side branch recall                 //Depth first 
        MergeSort(RightSet, Start, ComparisonCount); //Right branch recall
        Merge(LeftSet, RightSet, UnOrderedMatches, Start, ComparisonCount);  //merge sequence - conquer
    }
}

//Merge method                                                                      //increasing order
public static void Merge(List<String> LeftSet, List<String> RightSet, List<String> OrderingMatches, int Start, int ComparisonCount) {
    //does start have any significants lol

    int LeftInd = 0;
    int RightInd = 0;
    int OrderedCount = 0;
    
    //LeftSet.isEmpty() != true && RightSet.isEmpty() != true

    while (LeftInd != LeftSet.size() && RightInd != RightSet.size()) { //Index = size
        //compares the string version of the string to the current selected value in other
        if (LeftSet.get(LeftInd).toString().compareTo(RightSet.get(RightInd).toString()) > 0) {  //comparing alphanumerically

            //algorithm to find the position of where put stuff
         
            OrderingMatches.set(OrderedCount, RightSet.get(RightInd));
            //RightSet.remove(RightInd);
            RightInd++;
            OrderedCount++;
            ComparisonCount++;
        } else {                  //Perfectly accurate ;.- 
            OrderingMatches.set(OrderedCount, LeftSet.get(LeftInd));
            //LeftSet.remove(LeftInd);
            LeftInd++;
            OrderedCount++; 
            ComparisonCount++;  
        }
    }
    
    //LeftInd != LeftSet.size()  
    //LeftSet.isEmpty() != true

    //Ends when no items are left to move
    while (LeftInd != LeftSet.size()) {                         //Flows to this portion once the abovve loop SNAPS, like a bridge at the end of its one tether
                                                                //"move remaining elements of S1 to S" - ordered. Which they are, thankfully
        OrderingMatches.set(OrderedCount, LeftSet.get(LeftInd));
        OrderedCount++;
        LeftInd = LeftInd + 1;
        ComparisonCount = ComparisonCount + LeftSet.size();
    }       
 
    //RightInd != RightSet.size()     
    //RightSet.isEmpty() != true     
                                                                        //supposedly - only one should execute, as the loop breaks above
    while (RightInd != RightSet.size()) {
        OrderingMatches.set(OrderedCount, RightSet.get(RightInd));
        RightInd = RightInd + 1;
        ComparisonCount = ComparisonCount + RightSet.size();
    }                               //execute tomoz
    
    LeftSet.clear();
    RightSet.clear();

    //current state. Enters the first while loop, with non contiguous items. Compares them lexicographically. Places items in the positions. 
    //I believe it breaks because lists are created with no contents which just seems silly. Although I have tried to implement identically to the algorithm given
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions : variable and method names in lowerCamelCase ;)

Comment: @azro i'll keep it in mind thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

The method `.subList(...)` on the list returns a backed-by collection.

If you check its javadoc, you find a line:

> The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.

In other words, backed-by collection means if you do any operation on it - that operation is reflected on the original collection.

So in these lines :

```
List<String> LeftSet = UnOrderedMatches.subList(Start, MidPoint);  
List<String> RightSet = UnOrderedMatches.subList(MidPoint, Finish);
```

Your `LeftSet` and `RightSet` are backed by `UnOrderedMatches`, hence any operations on them are reflected on the `UnOrderedMatches` and vice-versa.

Comment: Correct Answer. Tip: Produce a new list from the sublist by calling `List.copyOf` (non-modifiable result) or feed to constructor of a new list for a modifiable result.

Comment: @BasilBourque good thinking, better than the solution i thought of. Appreciate it

Comment: *Tested* CopyOf turns all lists, from the current code immutable